# Do smartphones and computers cause skin to age via "tech neck"?

Tags: mobile-phones, dermatology

I was watching a health program on TV last night that was looking at skin aging, and they flashed up a panel showing various causes of skin aging. Along with the usual culprits of sunlight, smoking and drinking, there was also smartphones and computers listed.

Looking around the web, there is [this (slightly quackish?) site claiming](http://www.dnaindia.com/lifestyle/report-is-your-smartphone-ageing-you-2050865):

> studies have shown that excessive use of cell phones can affect the skin too. “Often referred to as ‘Tech Neck’, it is usually associated with the posture one assumes while using the phone. One constantly looks down and forward for hours causing the neck muscles to contract, thereby increasing the pull on the facial skin particularly over the jowl area. This increases the formation of wrinkles, possibility of skin sagging and also leads to a double chin.

A [previous answer](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/9869/6397) dealt with the question of temporary wrinkles becoming permanent, and it was a "probably true".

The [Daily Telegraph has a more detailed look](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/science/science-news/11338225/Smartphones-and-tablets-cause-skin-wrinkling-condition-dubbed-tech-neck.html), but it sounds a bit too much like an advert for:

> Beauty brand Yves Saint Laurent claims it is has invented the first cream which tackles ‘tech-neck’ with a new molecule to boost elasticity of the skin.

So, has there been some new research into this that makes specifically mobile phone users (rather than desk workers in general) more susceptible to "tech neck"?

Comment: Would be interesting to see how looking at a phone would cause more effect than, say, looking down at a book, magazine or newspaper, or simply just looking down for an extended time.

Comment: Yes, when I sit in front of the laptop, my head is slightly tilted to the front. If they had speculated about a possible orthopedic effect on the muscles of the neck I would not be as surprised. I fail to see how the posture can affect the skin (not even slightly). But who I am to dispute the Daily Telegraph?